# extract values from another worksheet based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

table 1, worksheet a

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| recipient | activity   | funding a | funding b from table 2 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| group 1   | basketball | 200       |                        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| group 1   | soccer     | 80        |                        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| group 2   | soccer     | 18        |                        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------------+
| group 3   | tennis     | 35        |                        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

table 2 worksheet b

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| recipient | activity   | funding b |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| group 1   | basketball | 100       |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| group 1   | soccer     | 50        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| group 2   | soccer     | 25        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| group 3   | tennis     | 30        |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

My objective is to insert the values from column 'funding b' from table 2 worksheet b onto table 1 worksheet a. Keep in mind this is a simplified table and that the values are unordered in my original worksheets.

I have tried entering the following in the 'funding b from table 2' cell of table 1 and got an error :

```
=INDEX(table2[funding b],MATCH(1,([@[recipient]]=table2[Recipient])&([@[funding a]]=table2[fundingb]),0))
```

I'm not sure how to proceed further so any help or hints would be appreciated either using formulas or power-query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to find the appropriate funding in the second table by searching for recipient and activity. If so, you can use the `SUMPRODUCT` function if the combination of recipient and activity is unique:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([@recipient]=Table2[recipient])*([@activity]=Table2[activity])*Table2[funding b])
```

If not unique, use `INDEX`/`MATCH` as array formula to return the first value found:

```
=INDEX(Table2[funding b],MATCH(1,([@recipient]=Table2[recipient])*([@activity]=Table2[activity]),0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: FYI, a `SUMIFS`/`MAXIFS` formulation will likely be more efficient than array formulas.

Comment: thanks, the sumproduct formula worked. A quick question though regarding its use, does the order matter in terms of the conditions? ie: reversing recipient with activity?

Comment: No, I was just trying to show that the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives (far less effective than @basic's answer). Use a column helper in table 2.
We create an id column with :

```
=CONCAT(Table2[@[recipient]:[activity]])
```

then we use a standard VLOOKUP.

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCAT(Table1[@[recipient]:[activity]]),Table2[#All],4,FALSE)
```

Another option : this horrible one liner (uses text functions) :

```
=INDEX($I$3:$K$6,(LEN(LEFT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,$I$3:$J$6),SEARCH(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,B3:C3),TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,$I$3:$J$6))))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,$I$3:$J$6),SEARCH(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,B3:C3),TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,$I$3:$J$6))),";","")))/2+1,3)
```

[image: Vlook]